# Clipping facebook app screen

Tags: facebook

I have tried a few Facebook apps for Windows Phone and I noticed that when viewing a picture or going into the comments and returning, the screen shifts like 1 centimeter to the left, clipping the screen so not abling to read the leftmost characters.

Does anybody has a solution for this?

I'm using a Lumia 640XL.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to illustrate, as I don't think I've seen this behaviour?

Comment: I've been using the Facebook official app and I can't seem to replicate what's happening to you.

Comment: I can relate,mine is doing the same thing and I ve no idea y.

Comment: @user23834 and Michel Is this happening in Facebooks app or the retired Microsoft one?

Comment: @user23834 Since the upgrade to Windows 10 all problems have been resolved for all FB apps. I cannot remember exactly which one I had, but it seems they all made use of the same FB engine/framework (with the related bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for helping others: the problem is solved by upgrading to Windows 10. It seems all apps using FB before were using the same engine/framework which has been resolved in Windows 10 OR it was a GUI bug inside an older version of Windows 10.

Comment: You could mark your post as answer.